# Aggregation of data on the basis of different attributes

Tags: java, cassandra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWLUN.jpg)I am facing problem regarding data aggregation,i am using cassandra and it is not facilitating me to do so..i want to make aggregated feed and trying to aggregate data on the basis of day verb actor target,Please let me know I am trying hard to do so.

[I have to show my data in aggregated format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpoP6.jpg)

Comment: Could you please add more details on the question?

Comment: I have some pieces of data,which columns are "actor","verb","date","some data related to activity" ,i want to query those data as such i group them on the basis of date first,then group those day basis data on the basis of actor and then those group data on the basis of same action performed (verb).